# How to make the compiler know a parameter is property name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, xunit

When using xUnit, if I put code :

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestCases
{
        // test data
} 
[Theory, PropertyData("TestCases")]
public  void Test(// some parameter){}
```

The compiler/resharper(I am not sure what make it work) know "TestCases" (the string parameter in the constructor) is the static property TestCases I defined.

What is the mechanism behind it?

Thanks for the comments.

Here's what I observe.
The string is highlighted as an error if there's no corresponding member with that name. 
Seems it is about the R#, when I turn it off the error won't show up anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? What are you observing? (This is almost certainly R# being smart, by introspecting your code...)

Comment: "know" when? Metadata is powerful feature but only when you inspecting type

Comment: Do you mean that xUnit knows that it should obtain the test cases by calling the TestCases method/property because you decorated your test method with `PropertyData("TestCases")`?

Comment: I suspect this means "know" in the sense that the string is highlighted as an error if there's no corresponding member with that name. That's what R# does for NUnit `ValueSource` attributes anyway.

Comment: The whole thing relies on the xUnit R# extension. I'll write up an explanation in the morning for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting highlighting, navigation and code completion on the `"TestCases"` string, this is one of ReSharper's features. Essentially, ReSharper is specifically aware of the fact that certain string identifiers actually relate to symbols found elsewhere. As a result, it offers you features *as if* the string you are entering was an actual identifier.